# Ensure a datatable is ordered by a value

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a complex algorithm which I am not going to explain here.  The code pasted below is doing some processing for each row, but I need to ensure that the table is ordered by a field different than the Primary Key.
I need to do this in this code, not in SQL, or in stored procedures; it needs to be done in .net just before the foreach.

NO LINQ IS ALLOWED, ITS .NET 2.0
THX

Your help is appreciated.

```
List<int> distinctREFMDossierIds = GetREFMDossierIdsFromBookings();
foreach (int refmDossierId in distinctREFMDossierIds)
{
    bool errorsFoundInDetails = false;
    bool errorsFoundInHeaders = false;
    wingsBookingInterfaceIdswithErrors.Clear();
    dicRows.Clear();
    sbWingsBookingInterfaceIds= new StringBuilder();    
    YBooking booking = new YBooking();

    foreach (UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow row in _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Rows)
    {
      //code
    }
```

Comment: Just wondering, why can't it be done in the sproc level or in the db level?

Comment: @JonH: on top of my head, I remember the Cisco telephony API where you have a bunch of method that returns a list of items in the order that Cisco decided.

Comment: @Pierre-Alain Vigeant - Good example thanks...

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ:

```
foreach(var row in _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface
                     .OrderBy(r => r. Something))
```

Comment: its and old project in .net 2.0 and its not allowed to change to 3.5, please give me another solution if possible

Comment: Unless you're still using VS2005, you can use LINQBridge.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort a DataTable like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.DefaultView.Sort = <Sort expression>;
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: thank you, this did the trick.   _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.DefaultView.Sort = "WingsDossierID ASC";
                foreach (UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow row in _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Rows)
                {

Answer (score 2):

```
WingsBookingInterface.Rows.OrderBy(item => item.columnName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a collection ( for example a List<> ) with the OrderBy extension method.